# include a file in a file requested by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to include a file in a file requested by AJAX ?
Is it possible to run a php or JavaScript script in a file requested by AJAX ?

this code works in the index.php file

```
        <div id="test">
    <script>
        $("#test").load("web_elements/nihongo/price_list_kumagai.inc"); 
    </script>
    </div> <!--<div id="test"> -->
```

When I try the same code in a file that is requested by AJAX it doesn't include the file.
In the included file I seem not to be able to run any script (not JavaScript, not php) HTML gets parsed correctly.

When I request this file by AJAX

```
    <h3>Price list</h3>

<script>
alert( "You are running jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery );
</script>

<p>
幼稚園<br>
</p>
```

the HTML shows normally but everything within the   tags is ignored.

Navigation

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc(language, '/home.inc')">ホーム</a>
```

LoadXMLDoc function

```
    <script>
function loadXMLDoc(language, pageString)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("page_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",language+pageString, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

the LoadXMLDoc function was before I used JQuery. Maybe I should replace it with load() from the JQuery library.

Comment: sometimes this may be the problem "Uncaught ReferenceError: language is not defined" remove this line and check again document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=language;

Comment: sorry, the document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=language; is to display which language the user selected (language is a JavaScript variable). I am going to remove this from the original post as it only confuses.

Comment: everything within the tags mean <script> tags ?

Comment: yes. I wonder if I have a JavaScript mistake somewhere in the navigation menu that breaks everything.

Comment: Checkout my answer.. is it helpful ?

Comment: instead of using .inc extension try with .php or .html

Comment: that doesn't make any difference. I also need to use .inc files for security reasons. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can include external js files using `jQuery.getScript()`

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "script",
    success: success
});
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

You can also use [**`.load()`**](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method

---

your code is working properly and load scripts when I remove 
`document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=language;` line:

**price_list_kumagai.inc**

```
<body>
    <h3>Price list</h3>
    <script>
        alert( "You are running jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery );
    </script>
    <p>
        幼稚園<br>
    </p>
</body>
```

**ajax load**

```
<div id="test">
    <script>
        $("#test").load("web_elements/nihongo/price_list_kumagai.php"); 
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry this does not make any difference. All JavaScript is ignored in the included file. I am going to post my navigation and the AJAX function.